# User data management and authentication combined with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

*I know this isn't a coding question so I'm not sure which SO Community this belongs under so I'll ask here and see if anyone suggests another Community.*

I'm using Firebase Auth to handle user authentication and Firestore as a database for data for each user.

When a user authenticates,

1. the Auth ID for that user is returned from Firebase Auth
2. then I take the ID and call the Firestore API to get the user data for that user.

Is there a way in Firebase to authenticate and have the data for the user in the same call?  Essentially combining the two steps of auth and user data in the above description.

Firebase Auth provides user data but only what is associated with their log in method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Most solutions I found either do one the other but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single API call in Firebase to sign in the user and get their their data from Firestore in one go.

You will either have to make at least two API calls to Firebase, or implement your own server-side functionality to combine the operations (for example in Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) and then call *that* from your application.